# How do I pull data from a specific column using Python and pandas in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm pulling data from a previously established df called police_2013_by_date. Within that df, there are columns named: shift, disposition_desc and unit.

I need to make a subset of data for all disposition_desc of "DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9" so that I can determine what percentage of all calls were for "DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9" for a particular year?

I've tried the following:

```
crimes_2013_disregard = police_2013_by_date.query('disposition_desc == "DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9"')
crimes_2013_disregard
```

which returned "UndefinedVariableError: name 'disposition_desc' is not defined. However, this exact code worked when I entered 'unit' or 'shift' instead of 'disposition_desc'.

Here's the subject data:

```
police_2013_by_date.head(4)
shift           disposition_desc             unit
A               SUBJECT WARNED               410C
A               DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9         415C
C               GONE ON ARRIVAL              433C
C               LOCATION/BUILDING SECURE     415C
```

Comment: Would `df[df["disposition_desc"] == "DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9"]` give you the data you're looking for? I can't test it right now unfortunately, so my apologies if it doesn't work.

Comment: Not quite. I r'cvd: KeyError: 'disposition_desc'

Comment: That’s strange. `disposition_desc` is the name of the column, right?

Comment: @BrandesMoore if you get KeyError using the two ways mentioned in the comment and by yourself, then you are somehow handling different dataframe or have typing mistake or changing/dropping the column.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems different from what you're really looking for.

```
police_2013_by_date.disposition_desc.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

will get you all proportion of disposition_desc, including "DISREGARD / SIGNAL 9".

But if the question only for getting the specific value in the column, then @Brandes' answer is correct